# Twig rendering : outside a td tag

Tags: php, twig

I have to render a field from my database who contains html text. Then, this field is rendered by a twig template, and is inside a td tag.
The variable is a bit long, for example let's take this one :

```
 <p><span style="line-height:1">salut</span></p>

 <p><span style="line-height:1">J'ai décidé <u>aujourd'hui </u>d'écrire en gras. Pourquoi, je ne sais pas mais bon de toute façon il me faut une phrase aussi longue que <strong>possibleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee </strong>alors tant qu'à faire...</span></p>

 <p>&nbsp;</p>

 <ul>
    <li><span style="line-height:1">Bref. Bye bye !</span></li>
 </ul>
```

In this case, my text will overflow like this :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42hYK.png)

So how to get this inside the td box ? I don't want to display only X characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the html `table`? Can you show us the Twig template (parts of it).

Comment: This is a CSS problem, not a `twig` one